# Neural network and XOR as a classification

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I read somewhere that mean squared error loss is good for regression, and cross entropy loss for classification.

When I tried to train XOR as a classification problem with cross entropy loss, network failed to converge.

My setting:

- Network is 2-2-2
- First output is signaling 0 and second 1 (so two classes of inputs).
- Cross entropy is used for calculating error in output layer of network instead of mean squared error.
- as a activation function, Im using logsig.

Apparently, Im missing something, where is my mistake ?

Comment: Please provide code.

Comment: Im sorry, I cant, I wrote my own lib for educational purposes, so even If I post code, it will be meaningless without lib. Thing is, do you know the flaw in my thinking ? For example, when training classical XOR, one must use tansig activation, otherwise it will fail to converge. You know, Im searching for this kind of problem, so I believe, lack of code is not a problem.

Comment: This is a programming website, if you have no code, then the question is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation of this network in Mathematica:

```
net = NetChain[{2, Tanh, 2, Tanh, 1, LogisticSigmoid}, "Input" -> {2}];

eps = 0.01;
data = {{0, 0} -> {eps}, {1, 0} -> {1 - eps}, {0, 1} -> {1 - eps}, {1,
      1} -> {eps}};

trained = 
 NetTrain[net, data, CrossEntropyLossLayer["Binary"], 
  MaxTrainingRounds -> Quantity[5, "Minutes"], TargetDevice -> "GPU"]
```

Which converges after a few thousand rounds. So, I don't think you're missing anything - there's probably a bug in your library

[image]